# Title of a Custom UIBarButtonItem from a UIButton not showing

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I made a custom `UIBarButtonItem` from a `UIButton`. The custom bar button is visible, the action works, the size is correct, and the background color can be seen; however the manually set title cannot be seen. maybe background is laid over the text? I'm not sure, help?

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIButton *resetButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
resetButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 30);
[resetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(speakPhrase:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
resetButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:19];
resetButton.titleLabel.text = @"RESET";
resetButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
resetButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
resetButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *resetBarBTN = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:resetButton];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = resetBarBTN;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the title for button of using `setTitle:forState:` for particular control states, replace your code with below

```
UIButton *resetButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
resetButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 30);
[resetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(speakPhrase:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
resetButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:19];

[resetButton setTitle:@"RESET" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //change this line in your code

resetButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
resetButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
resetButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *resetBarBTN = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:resetButton];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = resetBarBTN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTitle:forState to set button title. For example

```
[resetButton setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```